# Android Development in Hadoop

Tags: android

I am asking a very generic question. Lately there has been so much buzz relating to "Android", "Hadoop". Both of the technology has strong developer communities. I want to know if there is any way by which we can work on  map-reduce programming in Android OS. I am interested in implementing machine learning algorithms that can be used in Android OS. Would like to discuss more about this based on the feedback from the developers.